# How to use indexed Database with Metrostyle Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, indexeddb

I'm writing Web-App for Windows 8 using Java-script, i was looking for a database solution, i found Indexed Database Part of Internet Explorer 10 which is ok as Metro Style App using IE10 to host HTML, However i couldn't find any example on how to use Indexed Database for Metro-style App in JavaScript, Any one can provide a very sample example on how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mleroys link looks great for building a nice data adapter for the listview/flipview.

For a nice wrapper, take a look at:

https://github.com/grork/db.js

Which is a WinJS port of dB.js from Aaron Powell. It gives you chaining and what not.

Comment: i wonder if this supported by Microsoft as i don't want to end up having my app refused to be hosted in Windows 8 Store , as they reject any apps done using third-party component :(

Comment: Where did you see that? This is just code. Jquery is allowed, for example. As are winrt that you author, or bring in from other parties.

Answer (score 2):

IF you would need a greater level of abstraction, you could try using LINQ2IndexedDB - a LINQ like option for IndexedDB

http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

It would be the same as for IE10. See the MSDN doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920759(v=vs.85).aspx

For an example of how to implement a custom data source with IndexedDB, see: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/07/10/creating-an-indexeddbdatasource-for-winjs.aspx